# What material is this in my 1950s home's walls? Is it dangerous?

Tags: bathroom, materials

I am renovating an old bathroom. It's in a house built in the late 1950s in Germany. I have removed the bathtub. The bathtub was built in a box, which had tiles on the outside and this black material on the inside.

My question is:
What is this stuff? Is it asbestos? I need to know, because if it really is asbestic-material I cannot dispose it along with the "normal" debries.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It dosent look like any asbestos product I have seen, I know in earlier times straw was used right now with the photo resolution and contrast that's all I can think of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks "Sauerkrautplatte", aka [Holzwolle-Leichtbauplatte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holzwolle-Leichtbauplatte). It's made from wood shavings and cement, but no asbestos (AFAIK). They used to be common as a form of drywall and insulation (but are not anymore).

> Wood wool lightweight boards (also called HWL boards ) are building boards that consist of long-fiber wood wool and mineral-based binders . HWL panels are used as plasterable insulation panels both indoors and outdoors. Colloquially, they are often referred to as "sauerkraut plates" or "sauerkohlplatten".